# Eclipse egit staging: highlight comparison in the same way it is done normally for the java file

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

while working on my java code I have the dark theme activated and I really enjoy the highlighting.

However, when I switch to EGit to stage my changes I only get a basic highlighting that differs in many ways from the java perspective highlighting.

Is there a way to get the highlighting in Egit to look the same?

[Edit]

I am using using Eclipse 18-09 and should be more specific. It is not about the perspective but about the **Compare tab**.

Here you can see what I mean:

[image]

And the compare tab looks likes this:

[image]

It would be great if the compare tab uses the same highlighting and then his overlay to highlight the new lines.

Comment: Could you show exactly what you mean by a screenshot? Do you use the latest version of Eclipse?

Comment: @howlger thanks for the comment, I added the screenshots